# Разделение строки arduino ide

Tags: arduino

В TCP сокет приходит строка(каждый раз разное кол-во символов) на подобие такой:
ssid:pass
Исходная строка записана в buf_string
Как записать символы до : в char * ssid, а после в char * pass

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно.

```
char pSsidPass[];

char* pSsid;
char* pPassword;

pSsid = pSsidPass;
pPassword = pSsid;    
while( *pPassword != ':' )
   ++pPassword;
*pPassword = 0;
++pPassword;
// Чунга-чанга.
```